# How to Debug URL Rewrite Rules in ASP.NET Web.config

Tags: asp.net, debugging, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

**[UPDATED QUESTION - 2020-03-06]**

---

Here is my problem.

I am working on an ASP.NET website, where the URL rewrite rules are very complex.

As a result, it is difficult to discover which rules are matching for a particular URL.

I would like help finding the ASP.NET classes, code or events that process the rules in the web.config so that I can trace through the process that takes place while the URL is being handled by IIS.

I want to be able to see the URL and the result of each attempt to match a rule.

Does anyone know a debugging technique to use in the Visual Studio debugger or some type of print statements that I can use to trace this process?

Here is the documentation for the rewrite rules: [URL Rewrite Module Configuration Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference)

Below is an example that I have already debugged, showing the result of understanding the rules.  The rule "New2" is matched when testing.

Example:

```
<system.webServer>
...
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Mobile">
            <match url="^mobile$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="mobile.aspx" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Print rule">
            <match url="^([A-Za-z0-9/_-]+)/print$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="print.aspx?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="New paging1">
            <match url="^([A-Za-z0-9/_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9/_-]+)/([0-9]+)/page/([0-9]+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="default.aspx?parent={R:1}&amp;url={R:2}&amp;godina={R:3}&amp;page={R:4}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="New paging2">
            <match url="^([A-Za-z0-9/_-]+)/([0-9]+)/page/([0-9]+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="default.aspx?url={R:1}&amp;godina={R:2}&amp;page={R:3}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Page rule 1">
            <match url="^([A-Za-z0-9/_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9/_-]+)/page/([0-9]+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="default.aspx?parent={R:1}&amp;url={R:2}&amp;page={R:3}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Page rule">
            <match url="^([A-Za-z0-9/_-]+)/page/([0-9]+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="default.aspx?url={R:1}&amp;page={R:2}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="New">
            <match url="^([A-Za-z0-9/_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9/_-]+)/([0-9]+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="default.aspx?parent={R:1}&amp;url={R:2}&amp;godina={R:3}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="New2">
            <match url="^([A-Za-z0-9/_-]+)/([0-9]+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="default.aspx?url={R:1}&amp;godina={R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="rule 1">
            <match url="^([A-Za-z0-9/_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="default.aspx?parent={R:1}&amp;url={R:2}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Glavni rule 2">
            <match url="^([A-Za-z0-9/_-]+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="default.aspx?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
...
```

Comment: I see this question has had at least 3k views - so I thought it worth updating.  Further, following the answer provided, I was able to find the information I needed to solve my version of the OP's challenge.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This](http://damir.globaldizajn.hr/RegExp.aspx) is what I found after month of googling.
I looks poor but worked for me ...

Comment: Hi @manuel - This answer might have been better placed as a comment under your question - as it is not an exact solution.  There are other answers that point to reference material specifically about using IIS features to test URL Rewrite rules.  This might save you from the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can test your rules in your IIS Manager and it's quite simple. In short:

- open your IIS Manager, click needed website
- on central pane, in 'IIS' block, double click on 'URL Rewrite' icon - you will see a list of created in web.config rules (or empty
  list if they don't exist)
- select the rule you want to test, find 'Edit' button on right pane in 'Inbound Rules' block
- 'Edit Inbound Rule' page will be opened, find 'Test pattern' button and push
- here you can enter different urls in 'Input data to test' field (having 'Pattern' field filled) and click on 'Test' button to check
  the expression over your url, results will be shown below.

Full manual here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/testing-rewrite-rule-patterns

Comment: Following the reference and steps in this answer, I was able to find the exact same feature in Windows Server 2016 / IIS 10.x as of March 6, 2020.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Failed Request Tracing for this. It helps me a lot. [This](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) article describe how to use it in url rewrite. Use IE to view log files.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: this is complex but it is step in right direction. I was hopping somthing simpler :)

Comment: I had the same issue, this helped me a lot. Sorry I couldn't find a simple way than this :)